# How to parse form content in DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, dotnet-httpclient, message-handlers

I'm trying to create a custom [message handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers) which adds an `Authorization` header to all requests sent by an `HttpClient`. In order to compute the value of this header, the path of the request (including query parameters) must be concatenated with the the body of the request (which must have a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Since my use-case is very latency sensitive, I was wondering whether the code below is the most efficient/ fastest way of doing this? Or could it be improved? In particular, is there a better alternative to having to use `ReadAsStringAsync` to get the form data?

```
class AuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var path = request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
        var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
        // TODO: create "Authorization" header
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```